# Umbrella: "Take Three" lyrics

Tags: lyrics, meaning

In [Umbrella](https://open.spotify.com/track/49FYlytm3dAAraYgpoJZux?si=6b6884444d8b4b67) by Rihanna and JAY-Z, JAY-Z says "Take three, action" 7 seconds in. Does this mean that they had previously recorded this song 2 times and these attempts weren't as successful?

Answer (score 1):

"Take three" could have been a reference to recording a song fifty years ago when whole songs were recorded at once in a studio, but "action" makes it a reference to shooting a movie. You'd never hear the word "action" in a sound studio.